# tracking changes to text in text box python

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

i'm using pyqt5 with python and have a qtextedit widget. i want to track changes made in the textbox and log them. i'm able to anticipate when the text in the text box has changed, but i don't know a way of knowing exactly what the change is. i could save the initial text and the changed text in 2 seperate variables and compare the 2, but i would have thought this functionality would have been incorportated into pyqt5. before i try to implement this, could someone familiar with this package confirm whether or not such functionality is available or not?

thanks

Minimal Code:

```
display.textChanged.connect(update)

prev_text = ''

def update:
    display.text - prev_text #logic to compare codes
    prev_text = display.text #update global variable
```

Comment: Knowing what characters in a textbox have been modified is fringe? There's a signal to handle changes made in a textbox, I would have thought knowing what these changes are would have been standard!

Comment: Get the [`document()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#document-prop) and use the [`contentsChange`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#contentsChange) signal that provides the position in the document and the removed/added characters.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks musicamante, that answers what I was after, not sure how to mark it as an answer though!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to musicamante comment I've got this working.

Here's the minimal code that does the business:

```
display = QTextEdit()
display.document().contentsChange[int,int,int].connect(tracking)

prev_txt = ''
def tracking(pos,rem,add):
    global prev_txt
    current_txt = display.toPlainText()
    if add>0: #if add
        print('What was added: ', current_txt[pos:pos+add])
    if rem>0: # if remove
        print('What was removed: ', prev_txt[pos:pos+rem])
    prev_txt = current_txt
```